# Generic CRUD using JSF and PRimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, crud

I was looking for some general guidelines for creating a generic CRUD page using JSF (2.1) and PrimeFaces  (5.0)(specifically using PF's `<p:dataTable>` component). Some of my requirements are as follows:

- Dynamic number of columns (based on the #of columns of a selected Database Table)
- Inline editing
- Popup (dialog) edit

I have tried using `<p:columns>` component to show the dunamic #of columns, however, it seems I cannot use the inline editing feature `<p:rowEditor>` when I use `<p:columns>`

Any help in terms of suggestions/recommendations is highly appreciated. My goal is not to create seperate pages for each table but to use the same page (component) for multiple DB tables.

Comment: Why are you using <p:columns> instead of <p:column>

Comment: Because I don't know the # of columns in advance.